# change function is showing results after click on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, search, onchange

I have search input box where user types some characters then suggestion list pop up comes and when user select item from list then data gets auto-fill in some fields. I have used [Awesomplete widget](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#advanced-examples) for my search box.

**HTML**

```
 <input data-list="Samuel Mendoza, Bowie Tarren" class="awesomplete" style="display:inline-block;width: 371px; font-weight:bold;z-index:0"/>

<button class="fa fa-search" type="button" style="border:none;background-color: #ffffff;    margin-left: -33px; color: #dedede;position:relative; z-index:1"></button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".awesomplete").change(function () {
    var pt_name = $('.awesomplete').val();
if(pt_name == "Samuel Mendoza"){

        document.getElementById("first_name").value = "Samuel";
        document.getElementById("middle_name").value = "Ariel";
        document.getElementById("last_name").value = "Mendoza";
        document.getElementById("nickname").value = "Same";
        $("#gender").val('1');
        document.getElementById("dob").value = "18 Dec 1977";
        document.getElementById("street_1").value = "14 Tall Acres Drive";
        document.getElementById("street_2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("city").value = "Spring";
        $("#state").val('1');

        document.getElementById("postal_code").value = "77387";
        document.getElementById("tel").value = "713-251-2721";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "smendoza@protonmail.com";
        document.getElementById("mrn").value = "2457324";
        document.getElementById("insurance_carrier").value = "Blue Cross Blue Shield";
        $("#ref_service").val('16');
        $("#ref_physician").val('2');

        document.getElementById("date_ex1").value = "20 Jan 2017";
        document.getElementById("date_ex2").value = "20 Jan 2017";
        document.getElementById("date_ex3").value = "20 Jan 2017";

        $("#pt_nutritionist").val('1');
        document.getElementById("primary_diagnosis").value = "ICD-10";
        document.getElementById("secondary_diagnosis").value = "ICD-10";
        $("#problem").val('1');
        $("#etiology").val('1');
        $("#symptom").val('2');
        $("#food_access").val('4');


    }
  });
});
```

The problem now I am facing is that when I select item from popup of search box then fields are not gets auto-fill. However when I select item and click somewhere else then the fields gets auto-filled. Is it because of Awesomplete widget or change function?  I don't understand why this is happening.

I want that as soon as I select item from suggestion popup list then only the fields should gets autofill. The extra click should not required.

How should I get that? Can anyone please help me in this?

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** I guess my problem is not because of equality sign. My search showing result with = and with == this also. The problem is that requires extra click to display results.

Comment: I guess my problem is not because of equality sign. My search showing result with `=` and with `==` this also. The problem is just requires extra click to display results.

Comment: OK, then we need to see more code. Is your jQuery library loaded correctly, before the JS code? Are you using duplicate ID's on any fields? Are you getting any JS errors in your console?

Comment: @ jtheman - I have checked what you asked. I have JS code at the end of my page. There are no duplicate ID's. I am not getting any JS errors.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in the jsfiddle I posted below, it makes debugging much easier? Except my answer below there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var pt_name = $('.awesomplete').val();
if(pt_name = "Samuel Mendoza"){
```

to

```
var pt_name = $(this).val();
if(pt_name == "Samuel Mendoza"){
```

== is the comparison operator, not the single equal sign.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Also `$(this).val();` refers to the changed item, makes sense.

Then I suggest changing ALL the lines with `document.getElementById("` to the more simple jQuery syntax you use on the other lines.

IE change:

```
document.getElementById("first_name").value = "Samuel";
```

TO

```
$('#first_name').val() = "Samuel";
```

Much easier to read, even if the data population could be MUCH more efficient.

Comment: yaah, I tried that also but doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Well you need to have a correct comparison operator to EVER get the if() function to work.

Comment: Actually the code here DOES work as what you posted now, see https://jsfiddle.net/x8sjgh0a/2/ (add "Samuel Mendoza" to the first field)